# ILNumerics unable to read mat file of -v7 format

Tags: ilnumerics

I know ILNumerics handles mat file saved using -v6 or -v7.3 option quite nicely but anyone knows how to make it recognize files saved using -v7 option?

The -v7 option by default uses compression and hence ILNumerics will give me a message saying it does not support compressed file and suggests me using -v6 option to save the file.

I guess nowdays mat file saved using latest releases of matlab (like 2010 - 2014) prefer the -v7 file format against the -v7.3 format which internally uses HDF5 because of the overhead HDF5 causeds. And since compression it's also smaller in size than the -v6 file which also is a big advantage.

So can ILNumerics fill this gap? Or is there already a solution that I missed?

Thanks.